# Representing a combatant's equipment using the decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is this a valid implementation of Decorator Pattern? Are there any possible improvements? Also, it is possible to remove decorations in a simple way?

```
 public interface Enemy {
    void fight();

    String shoutIdentity();
}
```

```
public class UnarmedEnemy implements Enemy {

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        System.out.println("I'm fighting with you!");
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return "I'm your enemy! ";
    }
}
```

```
public class EnemyDecorator implements Enemy {

    private Enemy enemy;

    public EnemyDecorator(Enemy enemy) {
        this.enemy = enemy;
    }

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        enemy.fight();
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return enemy.shoutIdentity();
    }
}
```

```
public class BowDecorator extends EnemyDecorator {

    public BowDecorator(Enemy enemy) {
        super(enemy);
    }

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        super.fight();
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return super.shoutIdentity() + "I have a bow! ";
    }
}
```

```
public class ShieldDecorator extends EnemyDecorator {

    public ShieldDecorator(Enemy enemy) {
        super(enemy);
    }

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        super.fight();
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return super.shoutIdentity() + "I have a shield! ";
    }
}
```

```
public class SwordDecorator extends EnemyDecorator {

    public SwordDecorator(Enemy enemy) {
        super(enemy);
    }

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        super.fight();
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return super.shoutIdentity() + "I have a sword! ";
    }
}
```

```
public class HorseDecorator extends EnemyDecorator {

    public HorseDecorator(Enemy enemy) {
        super(enemy);
    }

    @Override
    public void fight() {
        System.out.println("I'm NOT fighting with you!");
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return super.shoutIdentity() + "I have a horse! I'm fleeing! ";
    }
}
```

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enemy enemy = new UnarmedEnemy();
        System.out.println(enemy.shoutIdentity());
        enemy.fight();
        System.out.println("\nYour enemy found a shield..\n");
        enemy = new ShieldDecorator(enemy);
        System.out.println(enemy.shoutIdentity());
        enemy.fight();
        System.out.println("\nYour enemy found a bow..\n");
        enemy = new  BowDecorator(enemy);
        System.out.println(enemy.shoutIdentity());
        enemy.fight();
        System.out.println("\nYour enemy found a sword..\n");
        enemy = new SwordDecorator(enemy);
        System.out.println(enemy.shoutIdentity());
        enemy.fight();
        System.out.println("\nYour enemy found a horse..\n");
        enemy =  new HorseDecorator(enemy);
        System.out.println(enemy.shoutIdentity());
        enemy.fight();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is this a valid implementation of Decorator Pattern?"_ How would you implement an enemy with shield and sword? Also check [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

Comment: IMHO the *decorator pattern* is not a proper implementation of an *inventory*. Eg.: ho would you implement the *upgrade* or *loss* of an item?

Comment: Like your previous questions, this question involving `System.out.println()` placeholders looks too sketchy to be realistic code. It's hard to review such code, and such skeletal questions border on being off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation is OK, note: I will add method which adds new behaviour dynamically, for example:

```
public class ShieldDecorator extends EnemyDecorator {

    ...
    private String addShield() {
        return "I have a shield! ";
    }

    @Override
    public String shoutIdentity() {
        return super.shoutIdentity() + addShield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply said: You mastered the decorator pattern.

But:

You have a misleading semantic. The application may be proper, but the usage ist not beneficial.

Any pattern identified has its inherent semantic and you have to analyze if the pattern matches the semantic you want to apply it on. It can even be, that there is nothing like a pattern.

In your case I would consider not to use a decorator pattern. I Think you have only simple associations.

Comment: _"Simply said: You mastered the decorator pattern."_ I don't really think so.